# synchronous rectifier controller having high voltage drain-source sense pin

Tags: high-voltage, pins, resonant-converter

I am looking for an IC that is suitable for synchronous rectifier operation and having high drain voltage sense pin. Most of the ICs (NCP4306, IR1168, UCC24612) are having drain sense pin up to 200-230V, although I need at least 300V drain sense pin. Is there any way to deal with a voltage higher than max. pin voltage?

Comment: Why? Explain what is the goal.

Comment: okay, it a synchronous rectifier IC for LLC resonant converter's secondary side. The output voltage is 150V and secondary side is center-tap topology. This means each secondary side mosfet's drain-to-source voltage sees 150x2=300V. Honestly, I overlooked the max. drain sense voltage of sychronous rectifier IC. I tried to use voltage divider but it failed.